# Get first word from a string -- which may be followed by a space or a punctuation mark

Tags: php, string, delimiter, text-extraction, sentence

I found this solution on Stack Overflow for getting the first word from a sentence.

```
$myvalue = 'Test me more';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0]; // will print Test
```

This is suitable when a space character is used to divide words. Does anyone know how to get the first word from a string if you do not know what the divider is? It can be ' ' (space), '.' (full stop), '.' (or comma).

Basically, how do you take anything that is a letter from a string up to the point where there is no letter?

E.g.:

- `House, rest of sentence here` would give `House`
- `House.` would also give `House`
- `House thing` would also give `House`

Comment: store the delimiter in an array, while using explode see if the delimiter matches to the list of array and take the value

Comment: [preg_split](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is what you're looking for.

```
$str = "bla1 bla2,bla3";
$words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);
```

This snippet splits the $str by space, \t, comma, \n.

Answer (score 4):

There is a string function ([strtok](http://php.net/strok)) which can be used to split a string into smaller strings (*tokens*) based on some separator(s).  For the purposes of this thread, the first word (defined as anything before the first space character) of `Test me more` can be obtained by *tokenizing* the string on the space character.

```
<?php
$value = "Test me more";
echo strtok($value, " "); // Test
?>
```

For more details and examples, see the [strtok PHP manual page](http://php.net/strtok).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) function with a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^\w*/', 'Your text here', $matches) > 0) {
  echo $matches[0]; // $matches[0] will contain the first word of your sentence
} else {
  // no match found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variability of your input string, there may be a few different approaches that will suffice.  If you want maximum control and reliability, I recommend a regular expression with `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()`.  I recommend `preg_replace()` over `preg_match()` because the latter generates an array, but the former directly returns the desired string.

```
/       #start of pattern delimiter
^       #match only from the start of the string
[a-z]*  #match zero or more letters
\K      #forget previously matched characters
.*      #match zero or more characters until the end of the string
/       #end of pattern delimiter
i       #match case-insensitively
```

- `strtok()` receives a "character mask" string as its second parameter -- this means that you can list single-byte characters in any order and it will return the string that comes before the first of any listed character.
- `sscanf()` is sometimes useful for parsing text, but in this case it is not as nice to play with if the string might not start with a letter.
- `str_word_count()` has its own definition of what a "word" is. It can consider apostrophes and hyphens as potential word characters depending on their position in the "word". You can even extend its definition by adding allowed "word" characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L6IJe))

```
$tests = [
    'House, rest of sentence here',
    'House.',
    'House thing',
    '',
    '!House fly',
    'House&Home',
];
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "Sample string : \t" . var_export($test, true);
    echo "\nstrtok() : \t\t" . var_export(strtok($test, ',. '), true);
    echo "\nsscanf() : \t\t" . var_export(sscanf($test, '%[A-Za-z]')[0] ?? '', true);
    echo "\npreg_replace() : \t" . var_export(preg_replace('/^[a-z]*\K.*/i', '', $test), true);
    echo "\nstr_word_count() : \t" . var_export(str_word_count($test, 1)[0] ?? '', true);
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Sample string :     'House, rest of sentence here'
strtok() :          'House'
sscanf() :          'House'
preg_replace() :    'House'
str_word_count() :  'House'
---
Sample string :     'House.'
strtok() :          'House'
sscanf() :          'House'
preg_replace() :    'House'
str_word_count() :  'House'
---
Sample string :     'House thing'
strtok() :          'House'
sscanf() :          'House'
preg_replace() :    'House'
str_word_count() :  'House'
---
Sample string :     ''
strtok() :          false
sscanf() :          ''
preg_replace() :    ''
str_word_count() :  ''
---
Sample string :     '!House fly'
strtok() :          '!House'
sscanf() :          ''
preg_replace() :    ''
str_word_count() :  'House'
---
Sample string :     'House&Home'
strtok() :          'House&Home'
sscanf() :          'House'
preg_replace() :    'House'
str_word_count() :  'House'
---
```